# How to tel a boost::karma::rule not to consume its attribute without providing a valid generator?

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-karma

Say we have the following source code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/spirit/include/karma.hpp>

namespace karma = boost::spirit::karma;

template <typename OutputIterator> struct grammar : karma::grammar<OutputIterator, std::nullptr_t()> {
  grammar() : grammar::base_type(query) {
    query =  "yeah";
  }

  karma::rule<OutputIterator, std::nullptr_t()> query;
};


int main(void) {
  typedef std::back_insert_iterator<std::string> iterator_type;
  std::string generated;
  iterator_type output_it(generated);
  //keys_and_values<sink_type> g;
  grammar<iterator_type> g;
  bool result = karma::generate(output_it, g, nullptr);
  std::cout << result << ":" << generated << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

This fails to compile because `karma` lacks some traits for `std::nullptr_t` (those are `boost::spirit::traits::extract_c_string` and `boost::spirit::traits::char traits`). More specifically, it fails because `karma` is not able to find a generator for an attribute of type `std::nullptr_t`.

I see several ways to cope with that:

1. **Replace `std::nullptr_t` by `karma::unused_type` in the grammar definition** : It works on this example but may introduce ambiguity in a more complex grammar.
2. **Defining the traits specialization** : In my opinion, this is dirty and not generic. Plus, it exposes my specialization of a standard type for everyone, leading to potential conflicts.
3. **[Specializing an attribute transform](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/advanced/customize/transform.html)** : Same problem of specializing a standard type just for me.
4. **[Write a custom generator](http://boost-spirit.com/home/articles/karma-examples/creating-your-own-generator-component-for-spirit-karma/)** : The best candidate so far, but it makes a serious load of highly templated code lines compared to the task complexity.
5. **Put a intermediate rule with a `karma::unused_type` attribute**. A quick fix that works but have no sense.

**Question** : How can I tell the `karma::rule` to generate a simple literal and not care about having or not a generator for its attribute ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to have stumbled on the inverse of the infamous *single-element fusion sequence* conundrum<sup>**[1]**</sup> :(

I noticed, because the error emanates from the code trying to verify that the input string matches the attribute (lit.hpp):

```
// fail if attribute isn't matched by immediate literal
typedef typename attribute<Context>::type attribute_type;

typedef typename spirit::result_of::extract_from<attribute_type, Attribute>::type
    extracted_string_type;

using spirit::traits::get_c_string;
if (!detail::string_compare(
        get_c_string(
            traits::extract_from<attribute_type>(attr, context))
      , get_c_string(str_), char_encoding(), Tag()))
{
    return false;
}
```

However, that makes no sense at all, since the **[docs](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/karma/reference/string/string.html)** state:

> `lit`, like `string`, also emits a string of characters. The main difference is that **`lit` does not consumes *[sic]* an attribute**. A plain string like `"hello"` or a `std::basic_string` is equivalent to a `lit`

So I just... on a whim thought to coerce things a little, by using the same workaround that works for *single-element fusion sequences* on the Qi side:

```
query = karma::eps << "yeah";
```

And, voilà: it works: **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2a80190a15ded2b2)**

---

<sup>**[1]**</sup> See

- [How do I use a class with only one attribute in a AST with Boost Spirit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7947180/how-do-i-use-a-class-with-only-one-attribute-in-a-ast-with-boost-spirit/7948257#7948257)
- [Spirit Qi attribute propagation issue with single-member struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19823413/spirit-qi-attribute-propagation-issue-with-single-member-struct)
- [Compiler error when adapting struct with BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21965388/compiler-error-when-adapting-struct-with-boost-fusion-adapt-struct)
- [Adapt class containing a string member as synthesized attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21511731/adapt-class-containing-a-string-member-as-synthesized-attribute)

Etc. This is a sad flaw that will probably need to be worked around for SpiritV2.

Comment: I just unearthed [this conversation on the mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/p/spirit/mailman/message/31608421/) that confirms that Spirit X3 is going to fix this issue. A related discussion on adapted sequences containing containers: http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/Error-with-container-within-sequence-td4642517.html#a4642520 (also put the question out on the mailing list, just to check that there's not a bug in `karma::lit`)

Comment: Yeah, that works great ! Thanks for the references. I'm happy to discover that I understood the doc correctly :)

Answer (score 1):

**Possible answer** : After posting this, I found a solution which satisfies me for the moment. That is : introduce a intermediate rule.

```
template <typename OutputIterator> struct grammar : karma::grammar<OutputIterator, std::nullptr_t()> {
  grammar() : grammar::base_type(query) {
    query =  null_rule;
    null_rule = "null";
  }

  karma::rule<OutputIterator, std::nullptr_t()> query;
  karma::rule<OutputIterator, karma::unused_type()> null_rule;
};
```

I'm still interested in any comment, reproach or other solution.